# What is the order of precedence to $\Gamma \vdash \phi \Rightarrow \psi$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In this context, $\phi$ and $\psi$ are formulas and $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas.

I'm not quite sure what it means. Does it mean $\Gamma  \vdash (\phi \Rightarrow \psi)$ or does it mean $(\Gamma \vdash \phi )\Rightarrow \psi$ ?

The following is the exact context of my question. It is from the Handbook of Proof Theory by Samuel R. Buss on page 6 (page 16 if including the preface, table of contents etc.)

[image: Excerpt from the Handbook of Proof Theory]

Also, if you could explain section (b) in more detail to me, that would be much appreciated as well. I don't think I really grasp it fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means $\Gamma\vdash (\phi \Rightarrow \psi)$. The alternative reading, $$(\Gamma\vdash \phi) \Rightarrow \psi \tag{*}$$ 
is a conceptual mess: $\Gamma\vdash \phi$ is a statement of the metatheory, $\psi$ a formula of the theory, and (*) seems to be a formula of the theory — or wants to be one, or something — but it isn't.

Re the reverse implication part of (b): if $\Gamma\vdash (\phi \Rightarrow \psi)$, then $\Gamma,\phi\vdash (\phi \Rightarrow \psi)$ too, so by *modus ponens*, $\Gamma,\phi\vdash \psi$.

Re the forward implication: This is by induction on lengths of proofs $C_1,C_2,\dotsc,C_{k-1},\psi$ of $\psi$ from $\Gamma,\phi$.

Comment: @BrianO, could you explain that last part again?

Comment: And @AndréNicolas, I don't understand how $(\Gamma \vdash \phi )\Rightarrow \psi$ has no meaning. To me it means, "If phi is provable by Gamma, then psi is true". Isn't this correct?

Comment: Yes,  I misused precedence. To be clear, it is $\Gamma\vdash(\phi\implies \psi)$.

Comment: OK, not it *doesn't have a meaning* but you have to clearly distinguish between if-then in the metatheory and the implication *symbol* $\Rightarrow$ of the formal language. And you should definitely **not** use the same symbol for both!, at least not until you've become clear about the distinction.

Comment: @BrianO, So how do you know which is which?

Comment: @Paul: I mistakenly thought I was commenting on your post. Your interpretation is not right, $\implies$ is part of the formal language, your version of bracketing does not give a formal sentence.

Comment: OK thanks BrianO, @AndréNicolas , I think I understand better now.

Comment: Just assume that $\vdash$ has lower/looser precedence than any of the logical connectives. Just as 1 + 2*3 is by convention 1 + (2*3) because + has lower precedence than *. But really a stronger statement can be made, and I did in my answer. People will write $\Gamma \vdash \phi\Rightarrow \psi$, without parentheses, because $\Gamma\vdash\phi$ just isn't a formula of the language, so it can't be combined with formal $\Rightarrow$ and any formula $\psi$. It's not even potentially ambiguous.

Comment: For reference: OP is asking about Buss's introductory Chapter 1 to *Handbook of Proof Theory*, available on his site [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/handbookI/ChapterI.pdf). The system $\mathcal{F}$ in use on p.6 is a Hilbert-style system.

Comment: Ok, so I'm assuming $\Gamma,\phi\vdash (\phi \Rightarrow \psi)$ means $(\Gamma,\phi)\vdash (\phi \Rightarrow \psi)$ as well?

Comment: Yes that's right. So $\vdash$ also has lower precedence than comma :)